# How can the upnName (user principal name) be set with BouncyCastle X509V3CertificateGenerator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I'm writing some unit tests for a pre-existing / functioning method in an application that gathers the *user principal name* from a given certificate via

```js
var upnName = currentUserCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.UpnName, false);
```

This works at run time however, I'm so far unable to retrieve this value from a BouncyCastle X509V3CertificateGenerator generated certificate. While I can get most of the way there I've been unable to generate a certificate that contains a *upnName*. I'm simply unsure how to set the *user principal* such that it may be retrieved via **GetNameInfo** when testing.

The test certificate itself is being generated as such

```js
private X509Certificate2 GenerateCert(KeyPurposeID keyPurposeId, string subjectPrefix = "OID.1.2.3.4=", string validCertOriginFragment = "OU=SOME ORG")
{
    const int keyStrength = 2048;
    const string subject = "98876543210123";

    // Generating Random Numbers
    var randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
    var random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
    var kpgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();

    kpgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), keyStrength));

    var certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    var certName = new X509Name($"{subjectPrefix}{subject} + CN=JAMES BOND (Affiliate), {validCertOriginFragment}, O=SOME ORG, C=US");
    var issuer = new X509Name("OU=CERT AUTH CA, OU=Certification Authorities, O=MYCERTAUTH, C=US");
    var serialNo = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

    certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNo);
    certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(certName);
    certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuer);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now.AddYears(50));
    certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now);

    // TODO setup upn name

    var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
    var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
    var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
    certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

    if (keyPurposeId != null)
    {
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(
            X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id,
            false,
            new ExtendedKeyUsage(keyPurposeId));
    }

    // Generating the Certificate
    var issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;
    ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA256WITHRSA", issuerKeyPair.Private, random);
    // selfsign certificate
    var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
    var x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

    return x509;
}
```

As per the suggestion by @peop adding the following to the TODO of setup upn name

```
certificateGenerator.AddExtension("2.5.29.17", true,
                                new GeneralNames(
                                    new GeneralName(GeneralName.OtherName,
                                                    new DerSequence(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"), new DerUtf8String($"{subject}@SOMEWHERE.COM")))
                                    ));
```

Has gotten me closer, I think, upon investigating the certificate I have an extra extension which is good, however the expected information is still not exposed via the GetNameInfo method. Is there something more that must happen to the certificate in order for the magical Microsoft GetNameInfo method to light up and return the expected value?

How do I create a certificate via the BouncyCastle X509V3CertificateGenerator such that I can retrieve the *upnName* for the sake of testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides [Guidelines for enabling smart card logon with third-party certification authorities](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/281245/guidelines-for-enabling-smart-card-logon-with-third-party-certification-authorities). In that document the specific format requirements for the certificate are enumerated:

> - The CRL Distribution Point (CDP) location (where CRL is the
>     Certification Revocation List) must be populated, online, and
>     available. For example:
>     [1]CRL Distribution Point
>     Distribution Point
>     Name:
>     Full Name: URL=`http://server1.name.com/CertEnroll/caname.crl`
> - **Key Usage** = Digital Signature
> - **Basic Constraints** [Subject Type=End Entity, Path Length Constraint=None (Optional)
> - **Enhanced Key Usage** =
>
>   - Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
>       (The client authentication OID) is only required if a certificate is used 
>       for SSL authentication.)
>   - Smart Card Logon (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2)
> - **Subject Alternative Name** = Other Name: Principal Name= (UPN). For example:
>     UPN = user1@name.com
>     The UPN OtherName OID is : "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"
>     The UPN OtherName value: Must be ASN1-encoded UTF8 string
> - **Subject** = Distinguished name of user. This field is a mandatory extension, but the population of this field is optional.

Given the format requirements and your certificate generation code (including the UPN you've added based on [pepo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293355/61654)) you need to modify the section where you are adding extensions to the cert:

```
if (keyPurposeId != null)
{
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(
        X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id,
        false,
        new ExtendedKeyUsage(keyPurposeId));

    // new extension not present in your question's code
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(
        "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2",
        false,
        new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth));
}
```

Doing this should create a cert that can be used as an `X509Certificate2` instance to `GetNameInfo(X509NameType.UpnName, false);`.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me and produced a certificate with a Subject Alternative Name attribute that was in the same format as a certificate produced by Microsoft Certificate Services when used for user/client authentication.  That is, when viewing the Subject Alternative Name attribute of the .cer file in Windows, you see:

```
    Other Name:
        Principal Name=john.doe@contoso.com
    RFC822 Name=john.doe@contoso.com
```

```
certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName.Id, false, new DerSequence(
            new GeneralName(GeneralName.OtherName,
                new DerSequence(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"),
                    new DerTaggedObject(0, new DerUtf8String("john.doe@contoso.com")))),
            new GeneralName(GeneralName.Rfc822Name, "john.doe@costoso.com")));
```

The key was to wrap the UPN string in a `DerTaggedObject`.  As suggested by [pepo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245057/pepo), I used the [ASN.1 Editor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) to view an existing certificate.  It had a bunch of **Context Specific** nodes around these values.  So doing research on that, I found [Tutorial for ASN1 DER Primitive Encoder](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-ASN1-DER-Primitive-Encoder#context-specific-tagged-object), which led me to the `DerTaggedObject`.  From there, I just started trying some code until the output of my generated certificate matched that from a certificate created by Microsoft Certificate Services.

Note also that the extension for Subject Alternative Name is not marked as **critical** (the second parameter to the `AddExtension` method is `false`).  This again matches what is produced by Microsoft Certificate Services.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/281245/guidelines-for-enabling-smart-card-logon-with-third-party-certification-authorities) UPN should be part of SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension.

> Subject Alternative Name = Other Name: Principal Name= (UPN). For example:
>   UPN = user1@name.com
>   The UPN OtherName OID is : "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"
>   The UPN OtherName value: Must be ASN1-encoded UTF8 string

Example of generating SAN extension using X509V3CertificateGenerator can be found [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/b19e68a517e56ef08cd2e50df4dcb8a96ddbe507/crypto/test/src/test/CertTest.cs#L1201).

```
// example of adding email address to SAN
certGen.AddExtension("2.5.29.17", true,
    new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.Rfc822Name, "test@test.test")));
```

So close, but we need `GeneralName.OtherName` which is defined [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/b19e68a517e56ef08cd2e50df4dcb8a96ddbe507/crypto/src/asn1/x509/GeneralName.cs#L38).

So my pseudo code (written in notepad) that should do the trick could look like this:

```
certificateGenerator.AddExtension("2.5.29.17", true,
  new GeneralNames(
      new GeneralName(GeneralName.OtherName,
        new DerSequence(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"), 
        new DerUtf8String(upnName)))
      ));
```

Hope I did the ASN.1 structure right - Sequence->(oid, utf8string). The best way would be to parse an existing certificate with i.e. [ASN.1 editor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) to check the ASN.1 structure of the extension.

Comment: This has gotten me closer, I think, upon investigating the certificate I have an extra extension which is good, however the expected information is still not exposed via the GetNameInfo method